# Php script query launches syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I´ve been trying to get this working for a while now, and I can´t seem to wrap my head around it.

```
$query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Player (PlayerID, Password, LoginIP) VALUES ('".addslashes($username)."'), password('".addslashes($pass)."'), ('".addslashes($IP)."') or exit("There was a error while registering, please try again in few minutes. <br><br>".mysql_error());
```

this is the error im getting

### You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to       your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password('chosenpassword'), ('127.0.0.1')' at line 1

Comment: debug 101. remove the `mysql_query(...) or exit( ...`. Then echo the query -> `echo $query2;`. You should then be able to see the error. If not, by running it directly in your db (ie. phpMyAdmin), it will also give you an idea.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find the errors.

Comment: well, if you have errors, you are probably getting an error message, especially since you have `mysql_error()`. If you want help, typically you should include the error message so that we can help you understand how to read the error message.

Comment: Edited my question & added error which i'm getting.

Comment: Well, your error tells you where to look. Something is happing before `password(...`. So what could it be? Your query has 3 column names `(PlayerID, Password, LoginIP)`. But look at `VALUES ('".addslashes($username)."'), password(...`. Due to the `)` at the end of your 1st value, before the `password(...`, your query only has 1 value (instead of the expected 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Player (PlayerID, Password, LoginIP) VALUES ('".addslashes($username)."', '".addslashes($pass)."', '".addslashes($IP)."') or exit("There was a error while registering, please try again in few minutes. <br><br>".mysql_error());
```

Please try this, actually you have used

```
password('".addslashes($pass)."'),
```

This is syntax error as you are getting, just remove 'password' and also you have one brackets around the each value but there should be only one bracket around all values.

Answer (score -2):

i think removing the dots, before and after the
    addslashes()
function should do it